About the Schauder Estimate in the paper of Yau regarding Calabi's conjecture
I'm trying to understand the paper
Yau, S.-T., On The Ricci Curvature of a Compact Kähler Manifold and the Complex Monge-Ampére Equation, I, Comm. Pure Appl. Math., 31 (1978) 339-411 (DOI)
Let $\varphi$ be a smooth solution to the complex Monge-Ampère equation on a compact Kähler manifold $M$ of complex dimension $m$
$$
\text{det}\left( g_{i\overline{j}} + \frac{\partial^2 \varphi}{\partial z^i\partial\overline{z}^j} \right) = C e^F \text{det}\left(g_{r\overline{s}} \right)
$$
The author finds estimates which depend only on $M$ for $\underset{M}{sup}\ \varphi$, the $L^1$-norm of $\varphi$. Moreover, writing $\Delta \varphi = f$, where $\Delta$ is the Laplace-Beltrami operator on $M$, he also establishes the following estimate:
$$
-m \leq f \leq C_1\ e^{C \underset{M}{sup}\ \varphi} e^{-C\underset{M}{inf}\ \varphi}
$$
where both $C,\ C_1$ depend only on $M$. He then proceeds to estimate the $C^0$-norm of the gradient of $\varphi$ by applying the Schauder estimate (see Morrey's book, p. 156 inequality (5.5.23) ):
$$
||\varphi||_{1, \alpha} \leq C' \left(||f||_{0, \alpha} + ||\varphi||_{L^1} \right)
$$
where $C'$ depends only on $M$, $\alpha \in (0,\ 1)$ is arbitrary and $||\cdot||_{l, \alpha}$ denotes the Hölder norm. From this, since we have estimates for $\underset{M}{sup}\ \varphi$ and
$||\varphi||_{L^1}$, the author asserts that
$$
\underset{M}{sup}\ |\nabla \varphi| \leq C_6 \left(e^{-C\underset{M}{inf}\ \varphi} + ||\varphi||_{L^1} \right)
$$
where $C_6$ depends only on $M$ and $C_1\ e^{C \underset{M}{sup}\ \varphi}$.
The problem is: I am unclear on how to derive RHS of the latter estimate using only the established bounds. Specifically, I do not see how one can get rid of the Hölder coefficient of $f$ using only the upper bound for $f$.
Any insight on addressing this issue would be greatly appreciated.
